# Facing issues while trying to read images from s3 with multiprocessing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

A newbie to multiprocessing, I have image name in my dataframe that is stored in s3 and I am trying to read that images and convert them to an array with multiprocessing. But getting error. Dataframe is like below table.

| image1 | image2 |
| --- | --- |
| img1.jpg | img1.jpg |
| img3.jpg | img4.jpg |

I want this data frame to be converted as an images array like below.

| image1 | image2 | array_1 | array_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| img1.jpg | img2.jpg | array of img1 | array of img2 |
| img3.jpg | img4.jpg | array of img3 | array of img4 |

I am trying to do this with multiprocessing, but getting run time error as -

```
    RuntimeError: This class is not fork-safe
```

Below is the code.

```
def img_array(image):
  '''read single image from s3 and convert to array.'''
  with fs.open(f's3://{bucket_name}/{folder_to_images}{image}' as f:
      open_image=Image.open(f)
      open_image.resize((224,224))
      img_arr=image.img_to_array(open_image)
  return img_arr

 def add_to_df(n):
  '''returns array for each of both images passes by Pool.'''
   array_1 = img_array(n[0])
   array_2 = img_array(n[0])
   return array_1, array_2

 P=Pool()
 result=P.map(add_to_df,df.values)
 P.close()
 P.join()
```

Please help me know how can I read images from s3 in multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the section of `P=Pool()`.

In *Safe importing of main module section* of python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods):

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python
> interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
> new process).
>
> For example, using the spawn or forkserver start method running the
> following module would **fail with a RuntimeError:**
>
> ...
>
> Instead one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__':`